# Combobox onchange javascript doesn't let me to open the combobox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a page with two comboboxes. Lets call them A and B. When selected index of A changes to a specific value, B is loaded from DB. It works fine on my side and I'm using ie7. The problem is, customer will be using ie6 and they say that the values are not loading when the value of A is changed. We know that the enable/disable value of the B is changed as it should but the problem is with the loading of values. Only way for me to test is by ietester and it works fine with that too.

Have you ever experienced such a problem? Any advice would be greatly appriciated.

Edit: Ok I was able to test it in ie6 and the problem is, I'm enabling the combobox B via javascript. It is enabled but when I click on the combobox, it is not opening down. It is like a fixed height is given for the drop down (1px). I'm able to change the value by clicking down from my keyboard. When I postback or reload the page, everything is fine since it is enabled on server side.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you implementing the combobox? Or do you mean a drop down menu? (A combobox is a drop down menu **combined** with a text field, hence the name, but HTML doesn't have a native combobox input type).

Comment: Can you post the code that disables and enables combobox B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and fixed it, sorry i couldn't post any earlier. To help others, The problem was with

```
document.getElementById('<%= ddlShipment.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
```

Looks like IE6 has some hard time to enable combobox. What I did to fix this was, I changed the display style of the row that contained the combobox from hidden to inline in my javascript:

```
document.getElementById('<%= ddlShipmentRow.ClientID %>').style.display = 'inline';
```

Why it worked? Because it rendered the combobox on load and it was already there when the page loaded, all i did was to change the display style and it worked. Hate IE6..

Thank you :)